# Harbor registry installation/upgrade

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, harbor

I recently started working with docker image registry called Harbor. I could not find any tags related to that.

My scenario: in one of the servers at work, there is harbor installed, along with docker, docker compose etc. Harbor site works fine. Harbor is basically a container in itself, which means multiple containers can be run on the server. I need to provide the dev team with Harbor v1.7. It is better from a security standpoint and has good LDAP integration. The Harbor that we host is very old version: 0.4.5.

My questions:

I searched and could not find a way to include two containers, only how to upgrade. If the former is possible, then can you please advice on how should I go about it? Which configuration files need to be changed, etc? Any links would also be greatly appreciated. At the moment all options are to upgrade the existing containers which is more work. At the moment I am aiming blind.
Since the requirement is v1.7 which use postgressql and mysql was only used till v1.5. If I do upgrade, would it cause a lot of issues with respect to tables, schema and db structure?

Answer (score 0):

Does v0.4.5 have replication capabilities? If so it might be easier to just stand up a fresh install of v1.7 and replicate the images from the old registry to the new one.

I just did an upgrade for v1.6 to v1.7 and that was one of the paths I considered.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I had another question - would the differences in database type cause any problem?

Comment: I don't think so, but it would always be good to do a test before hand. You may want to spin up a new instance on a local machine and see if you can replicate an project or two to the new instance to confirm.

Also here is the migration guide from v1.6 when they switched to Postgres. https://github.com/goharbor/harbor/blob/release-1.6.0/docs/migration_guide.md

Comment: Be carefull, the user guide states "Due to API changes, replication between different versions of Harbor may be broken." https://github.com/goharbor/harbor/blob/master/docs/user_guide.md#replicating-resources

Answer (score 0):

Currently harbor can't change authorization mode when there are previously added users.

There is replication capabilities, but can be broken between harbor versions: https://github.com/goharbor/harbor/blob/master/docs/user_guide.md#replicating-resources

I have endure myself a migration to OIDC autentication and the esiest way was create a mint-new one, copy the images and charts from one to the other, stop the older one and change the endpoint to the new one.

I have available a little program to copy images, but sadly no more: no charts or labels https://github.com/chusAlvarez/harbor-replication/